# Problem with Visual Studio and SharePoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-server

I installed Visual Studio 2010 to do with workflows in SharePoint 2010, but when I try to create a new project, Visual Studio says I don't have a SharePoint Server. I work through an external server SharePoint 2010. How I can connect to that server?

Answer (score 1):

you cant! needs to be on a local server like a virtual machine.... you develop and then package. once packaged you deploy on the server! You can use api's but they are limmited:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529917/sharepoint-2010-development-with-visual-studio